# Address unreachable in Android Emulator also when runned with google DNS

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have been trying to run correctly the default Android emulator for many hours. Each time, despite setting the DNS address 8.8.8.8, I get the error -2 -> ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE. When I runned the GenyMotion emulator, then the internet works, but on the default emulator I can not get the connection. What can I do more? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: I downloaded different AVD Device with lower API. In Android P in my case internet doesn't works.